# Getting ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PythonMagick' in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, imagemagick, pythonmagick

I am trying to import **PythonMagick** but not able to import this module. Could you please help me how to install it and use it in my code?

I tried several methods-

```
python -m pip install PythonMagic
python -m pip install PythonMagic --user
```

I downloaded the Imagemagic and ghostscript and given their path in environment variable. But didn't get any solution.

Comment: I suggest you use Python Wand. See https://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.2/

Answer (score 1):

Try downloading whl file from [https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/#pythonmagick)
then install with `python -m pip install <whl file>`

Comment: ERROR: PythonMagick-0.9.19-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: what python version are you using? cp39 means it needs python 3.9

Comment: ERROR: PythonMagick-0.9.10-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

Comment: I am using python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Please note that PythonMagick is a boost.python library that [requires Python 2.2](https://pypi.org/project/PythonMagick/#description). Unfortunately, it won't work with Python3 and newer. Most likely, it also won't work with Python 2.7.